# mySQL DateDiff Hour by Date

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

I am looking for some ideas on how to accomplish a date difference in hours while grouping by date in mySQL. For example, the normal DateDiff (Hours) method on the below dates will result in 49 hours, but I am interested in which days had which share of the total 49 hours:

```
Date 1: 2016-06-12 12:00
Date 2: 2016-06-14 13:00
```

Result:

Start                                    End                        Diff
2016-06-12 12:00     2016-06-13 00:00  12 Hours
2016-06-13 00:00     2016-06-14 00:00  24 Hours
2016-06-14 00:00     2016-06-14 13:00  13 Hours
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a calendar table with one row per date?

Comment: I do not. But that's an easy piece to have included in the solution if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a calendar table and the start and end dates are in variables, then logic like this should do what you want:

```
select c.date, c.date + interval 1 day,
       timstampdiff(hour,
                    greatest(c.date, $start),
                    least(c.date + interval 1 day, $end)
                   )
from calendar c
where c.date >= date($start) and c.date < date($end) + interval 1 day
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it out now and let you know.

Comment: There's a couple flaws that I am trying to work through. I.e., a table of dates (where each date starts at midnight) will not work with this... because the first date starts at 12:00 PM.

Comment: @JasonWasho . . . I think extracting the date portion should fix that problem.